# Como inserir gif animado no pygame

Tags: python, imagem, pygame, gif

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um trabalho do faculdade, é um jogo em python e preciso inserir um gif no código mas quando uso o comando `pygame.image.load("correr.gif")` ele monstra a imagem do gif congelada, ficando apenas uma imagem em png. Alguem pode me ajudar

segue o código inicial :

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
x = 352
y = 500
velocidade = 15
fundo = pygame.image.load("fundo_pista.png")
homem = pygame.image.load("correr.gif")
```

Comment: Erick, por favor, poste o seu código como exemplo, o que você fez até agora, como tentou etc.

Answer (score 2):

A biblioteca pygame pode ler imagens e exibir imagens estáticas com poucas chamadas. Mas nao tem suporte a GIFs animados. Se quiser exibir uma animação em gif em Pygame, terá que usar uma biblioteca com suporte mais completo a GIF - por exemplo, a "pillow", extrair os frames e indicações de tempo desejadas, e exibir cada frame manualmente (chamando o método "blit" da sua tela no pygame, e o pygame.display.flip() )

Então - vamos lá:

A Pillow pode ser instalada como "pip install pillow"  - e aí, ela sabe carregar uma imagem, verificar se é uma animação, e extrair todos os frames.

Agora mesmo usando a PIL, não é possível obter quanto tempo é esperado para
cada frame (o formato GIF permite que cada imagem fique sendo exibido por um tempo personalizado -então você pode ter uma imagem parada por 3 segundos, e uma animação em sequência rápida). Acredito ser razoável trabalahr com 100 milisegundos (10fps)
para cada frame - podemos usar o método `.tick()`
 de uma instância de  `pygame.time.Clock` para isso.

Aí acontece que objetos do tipo Image do PIL não são compatíveis com objetos "Surface" do Pygame - é necessário converter de um tipo para o outro. 
As duas bibliotecas permitem traduzir imagens de e para uma sequência de bytes - 
(na PIL o método chama "tobytes", e na pygame, por conta do método ter sido
criado ainda no Python2, se chama "fromstring" - (mas aceita um objeto bytes))
Além disso, imagens em GIF usam o modo de imagem de "paleta" com um número reduzido de cores, elas tem que ser convertidas pra RGB antes de ser feita a conversão. (Trabalhar com paletas direto poderia ser possível, mas seria mais complicado).

A melhor forma de fazer essas duas pequenas operações é escrever uma funçãozinha
para cada uma dessas coisas:

```py
import sys

import pygame
from PIL import Image

size=(800,600)
FORMAT = "RGBA"


def pil_to_game(img):
    data = img.tobytes("raw", FORMAT)
    return pygame.image.fromstring(data, img.size, FORMAT)

def get_gif_frame(img, frame):
    img.seek(frame)
    return  img.convert(FORMAT)


def init():
    return pygame.display.set_mode(size)

def exit():
    pygame.quit()


def main(screen, path_to_image):
    gif_img = Image.open(path_to_image)
    if not getattr(gif_img, "is_animated", False):
        print(f"Imagem em {path_to_image} não é um gif animado")
        return
    current_frame = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        frame = pil_to_game(get_gif_frame(gif_img, current_frame))
        screen.blit(frame, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        current_frame = (current_frame + 1) % gif_img.n_frames

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        screen = init()
        main(screen, sys.argv[1])
    finally:
        exit()
```

(a conversão de imagens entre pil e pygame, eu adaptei a partir
do código aqui: https://riptutorial.com/pygame/example/21220/using-with-pil , 
a documentação para ler frames no PIL aqui: https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/extract%20frames%20from%20animated%20gif )

Se for necessário ter o timing de frames de dentro do GIF isso tem que ser
adaptado, e temos que 'descer' até o código do PIL que lê os GIFs 
e pegar os dados de lá - no limite, depois de pesquisar isso, fariamos
uma sugestão de melhoria (com pull request), à própria Pillow.